# Mongoose - How to retrieve an array of objects from each document in collection?

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, mongoose

Each document in my collection looks something like this (JSON):

```
{
name: "Roger",
matches: [
    {
        opponent: "Rafael Nadal",
        match_date: 1494536400000
    },
    {
        opponent: "Nick Kyrgyos",
        match_date: 1494557400000
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract all the matches each player had and also sort them by `match_date` using Mongoose, but I don't know how.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$matches" },
  { "$sort": { "matches.match_date": 1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "matches": { "$push": "$matches" }
  }},
  { "$limit": 20 },
  { "$project": { "matches": 1, "numberOfMatches": { "$size": "$matches" } }}
])
```

Comment: I received the following error: `Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true` fixed it with `.allowDiskUse(true)`. I want to also use pagination (limit()), but only after the sorting have been successfully done. Do you know how? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `$limit` before the `$project` stage here... Updated the answer

Comment: Is there a way to "not group" the result? I want all the tennis matches for all tennis players

Comment: I couldn't get you... Can you please ask a new question with the sample output... It would be better for me to explain it in new answer